# Is it possible to customize UI of Google Custom Search's UI and the result?

Tags: google-custom-search

Today, I found there is Google Custom Search to improve websites' search features as I'd been pretty struggling for having better results on my website search engine. However, on my website, the result page is supposed to show some images with a Javascript-rendered carousel slider.

If possible I would like to hook up the carousel slider with the results. Even though I've googled about it, what I found is just "Look and Feel" on Google Custom Search, which is a basic-level customization for fonts or colors.

Does anyone know if Google Custom Search is a editable library?

Answer (score 0):

The [Custom Search JSON API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) might be a better fit for this use case.  The GCS Search Element can be styled with CSS, but trying to get the results into a carousel sounds implausible.